# Why can't I create multiple OAuth 2.0 client IDs for the same package name?

Tags: android, oauth, google-play-services

In the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling), it's stated that it's perfectly possible to use two OAuth 2.0 client IDs for the same package name.

> You should create two client IDs, one with the release certificate
>   fingerprint and another with the debug certificate fingerprint. Make
>   sure to use the same package name for both. This allows Play Games
>   services to recognize calls from your linked APKs that are signed with
>   either certificate

So I follow the tutorial in the link above: first go to `Game Service` in `Developer Console`, `Add a new Game`. Then I add a `Linked app` with this Game, it requires me to create an OAuth 2.0 client ID. After creating the first client ID with my release key's SHA1 , I cannot find any button to create another client ID. So I go to [Cloud Developer Console](https://cloud.google.com/console/project) and found out that I can create a second client ID here under `APIs & auth`-> `Credentials`. I use my `debug.keystore` 's SHA1 for this second client ID. Then I compile and test my example game with both the debug key and the release key.

However, after have run the app and attempted to sign in, the result is that only the app using the release key (using the first client ID) is accepted, while the app using the debug key (using the second client ID) is not accepted.

Then I try to delete my release key's client ID in the Cloud Developer Console (so that the debug key's client ID remains as the  only client ID there) and test my app again. This time, the app using the debug key is accepted, and the app using the release key is of course not accepted.

So does this mean that I cannot create multiple OAuth 2.0 client IDs for the same package name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained in the red warning note in the same [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id):

> Warning: Do not create new client IDs for your game from the Google Developers Console. If you do so, Play Games services will not associate your game settings with the client ID, and this could cause errors during gameplay.

Instead, in the Game Service part of the Developer Console, go to `2. Linked Apps` and select `Link another app` and follow the directions there, giving it a name such as 'Game Name Debug' and using your debug key SHA1 (every other field should be the same as your release app).

Comment: Man, I was stuck on this for an while because when I linked the second app, it did not present the "Authorize this app" screen. If that happens to anyone, simply delete the linked app and re-add.

Comment: The real thing here is to give a different name for the debug version, otherwise it won't show the "authorize" option again!

Comment: Well, it seems now that this does not apply anymore. I tried to to link my app using a dummy package name, in order to force the Authorize section to appear. However, when tried to changed the package name back to the original, I saw that is was disabled.. :(

Comment: So since package name cannot be changed, there is no solution for adding multiple keys for the same app?

Answer (score 1):

An additional note:

You have to specify a different **package** in Google Play services when linking the second app. If you do not specify a different package, then the "Authorize" section will not appear. Then, in the authorize section you can specify the original package (if you want to use only one package for not changing manifests). Is a bit cumbersome and weird but it works.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me! It was specifically this that confused me, the phase was hidden until i added a second package name.

Comment: Well, it seems now that this does not apply anymore. I tried to to link my app using a dummy package name, in order to force the Authorize section to appear. However, when tried to changed the package name back to the original, I saw that is was disabled.. :(